# I need to get the value of the latest entry in a Row in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to automate a process using Selenium on Python.

I need to search for an account in the search bar. The value to be entered in the search bar will be stored in an Excel file and updated every time a new account is to be searched.

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_tbxAcctSearch")
inputElement.send_keys('Value to be added here to search which is stored in excel')
```

I have the idea that I would need to get the value stored in a variable and then get the variable in the `inputElement.send_keys('variable')` -- but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you have to periodically search for an account, you have to iterate over the entries in that excel file.

So in the idea you mentioned, that variable is a `list`. Basically you have to store the entries in your excel file to a list, `account_to_search_list` variable then iterate over it:

```
for i in range(0, len(account_to_search_list)):

  '''do standard selenium path or button searching here''' # Do what you have to do here- which browser element you need to click or check for existence, etc.

  inputElement.send_keys('account_to_search_list[i]')
```